# foreman in test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman

Simple question. How to start Rails using Foreman in test env?

`RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec foreman start`
// starts in develop

`bundle exec foreman -e test start`
// bombs

`bundle exec foreman start  -e test`
// bombs

Answer (score 1):

Foreman has to point to a Procfile, or Procfile has to exist in the current directory.

```
# Procfile
rails s
```

Then you'd run

```sh
foreman start -f Procfile
```

It's common practice to keep a Procfile.test, Procfile.dev, etc.

```sh
# Procfile.test
rails s -e test
```

Hope that helps :)